# What is the smallest solution of $42!+k=P18\cdot P18\cdot P18\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

> What is the smallest positive integer $k$ , such that $$42!+k$$ splits into three primes with $18$ digits ?

My currently best result is $$k=31449145975909$$ http://factordb.com/index.php?query=42%21%2B31449145975909

I found this result by choosing random primes $p$ , then choosing $k$ minimal with $p\mid 42!+k$ and factoring the rest. This gives better results than just dividing $42!$ by two random primes , but still the results are probably much too high. Is there a better way than brute force ?

Comment: If we just pick the first two primes randomly and then take the samllest suitable prime as third, it will typically be $\approx \frac12\ln 10^{17}\approx 19$ too big, thus producing an offset of typically $2\cdot 10^{35}$. With this in mind, your $k\approx 3\cdot 10^{13}$ seems to be exceptionally small already. Then again, we have a lot of $P18$ at our disposal for trying ...

Comment: Enzo Creti found the solution : $k=279\ 557$. Probably, it is the optimal solution.

Comment: After seeing Enzo Creti's $k$, I started brute-forcing.  $k=193$, $k=6211$, $k=12973$ could be called "near misses" (three primes, smallest $>10^{15}$), still a lot to go ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for your double-check.

Comment: ... continuing brute force, $k=31387$ has smallest prime $\approx 7.6\cdot 10^{16}$. This is best so far up to $k=75000$.

Comment: Closing remark: Yep, $k=279557$ is the optimal solution